# Issue with string size in power builder

Tags: powerbuilder

I am trying to create dynamic data store at run time from code.

Syntax is like:

SQLCA.SyntaxFromSQL(ls_all_sql,"style(type=tabular)",ls_error)

There is only one column returning from it and the data type is long varchar.
But when it created data store, it is taking max char(32766) and rest of the data are lost.

Please advice to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the string limit in a text column of a datawindow / datastore is 32k.

Anything bigger must be accessed using a `select blob` statement.

Comment: Is it possible to use blob in dynamic data window? >> If it is possible, then please provide some example for it. It will be really helpful to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1318718: `select blob` does not involve datawindow. You must use it to get a text longer than 32k in your code but a datawindow *cannot* handle more than 32k in a text column.